# Java serversocket how to write and read to different threads

Tags: java, sockets

I am implementing a server using Java ServerSocket and have two clients connecting, each from different threads. One sends a message to the server and one reads a message from the server. They both contact the server on the same port, so how do I differentiate between a client that wants to read and one that wants to write?

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
while (true) {
    Socket cs = ss.accept();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()));
    String message = r.readLine();
    System.out.println("message");

    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
    String send = "send";
    os.writeBytes(send);
}
```

The last writeBytes causes problems since a client that connected in order to send a message to the server has already closed the connection. Similarly, a client that wants to receive from the server isn't going to submit anything on the socket's input stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make the client write a byte or a String after opening the session indicating if it wants to read or write, you can't really do this magically if they connect to the same port, unless you could differentiate them by ip address or something

Comment: @user1190650: In other words - you have to specify and implement an application specific protocol...

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple purposes of what happens when connecting to the same port, you must establish a protocol for the connection so the client tells the server what kind of client it is, and the server behaves accordingly.

For trivial protocols you can simply have the client write an initial byte telling what kind of client it is, and the server then behaves accordingly.  For even slightly more advanced protocols it may be the easiest to reuse an existing protocol for which robust implementations already exist.

In your current situation, the protocol is trivial, but you may very soon run into more complex scenarios.  Here a REST-ful protocol on top of http will most likely be a good chocie.